# Fragment Slide transitions not in sync

Tags: android, android-fragments

When the user advances to the next Fragment, I simply want them to slide, as if using a ViewPager. So I tried:

```
public void replaceFragmentSlide(Fragment newFragment) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Slide slideFromRight = new Slide();
            slideFromRight.setSlideEdge(Gravity.END);
            Slide slideFromLeft = new Slide();
            slideFromLeft.setSlideEdge(Gravity.START);

            Fragment oldFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container_detail);
            if (oldFragment != null) {
                oldFragment.setExitTransition(slideFromLeft);
            }

            newFragment.setEnterTransition(slideFromRight);
            newFragment.setExitTransition(slideFromLeft);
        }
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container_detail, newFragment, newFragment.getClass().getName())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
```

The visual effect is bizarre. The entering Fragment starts moving quickly, then slows down at the end. the exiting Fragment starts moving slowly, then speeds up at the end. They should match speed at any given moment, their borders just touching as the transition occurs.

What am I missing?

Comment: I am just starting to look at this area, so I may be off base. It seems to me that you need to somehow link the two transitions - maybe through [TransitionSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/TransitionSet.html) or [TransitionManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/TransitionManager.html).

Comment: That tip led me to some Googling that gave me a hint in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Just as I thought, the answer was so obvious as to make me stupid.

As I noted, the two transitions accelerated and decelerated differently. This is the result of their interpolators. So all I need to do is ensure they both have the same interpolator. It can be as simple as:

```
slide.setInterpolator(new FastOutSlowInInterpolator());
```

When both Slide transition animations have the same interpolators, they will move at exactly the same speeds, smoothly in sync.